# How to link an xml document to a Relax NG schema using the xml-model tag?

Tags: xml, xml-validation, relaxng

I wish to link an xml document to its Relax NG description document, using the `xml-model` tag as specified in its [W3C draft](http://www.w3.org/XML/2010/01/xml-model/).

`<?xml-model href="" type="" schematypens="" charset="" title="" group="" phase="" ?>`

Do you have a full example to show how to use it? Are there validator tools that understand the xml-model tag?

EDIT:  I saw the example here [Suggested use of schematypens](http://www.w3.org/XML/2010/01/xml-model/#d29e669).  I guess the only question remaining is which tools use xml-model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The example given in the spec is enough for RELAX NG:

```
<?xml-model href="http://www.docbook.org/xml/5.0/rng/docbook.rng" schematypens="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0"?>
```

Or, if you are using the compact syntax:

```
<?xml-model href="whatever.rnc" type="application/relax-ng-compact-syntax"?>
```

oXygen XML does support this specification.

Comment: I appreciate that you specifically included the compact syntax. Can you provide a reference for this?